# What can I do to prevent issues with my npm project when someone unpublishes their dependency?

Tags: javascript, npm

Question related to the `left-pad` [controversy](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2016/03/23/npm_left_pad_chaos/).

What can a developer relying on such dependencies do to minimise/prevent the impact of something like this happening again?

Comment: Store the previous dependncy in a file. Then use the package.json for all your other projects...